# Alternative for JPA @PrePersist for Firestore (Spring Cloud GCP)

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, spring-cloud

I am working on an application with Spring Boot and `FirestoreReactiveRepository`, however I cannot find an alternative to JPA's `@PrePersist`, I require it mainly for auditing purposes.

Document Class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.google.cloud.firestore.annotation.DocumentId;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.firestore.Document;

import java.util.Date;

@Data
@Document(collectionName = "vendors")
public class Vendor {

 @DocumentId private String vendorId;

 private Date createDate;

 private Date lastModified;

 private Boolean enable;

 }
```

Repository Class

```
import com.joltzly.canonical.entities.Vendor;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.firestore.FirestoreReactiveRepository;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

public interface IVendorRepository extends FirestoreReactiveRepository<Vendor> {

Flux<Vendor> findAllByAgentId(Integer agentId);

}
```

The idea is to be able to fill the fields `createDate`, `lastModified`, `enable` with that hook

```java
private Date createDate;
private Date lastModified;
private Boolean enable;
```

Comment: I don't see `@PrePersist` in your source code?

Comment: It is an annotation that is imported from JPA (javax.persistence.PrePersist) that is used in the class annotated as @Entity, in this case I am not using JPA, but org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.firestore.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't show pictures of code.  Copy the code into the question and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.